# Disable Mouse Hover and Selection for selected items in CustomListbox

Tags: c#, wpf, listbox, wpf-style

I created a custom listbox and based on a bool I want to disable mouse hovering and mouse selection for few items. I used the Style class and set the style in the code of custom listbox. My code is as follows:

```
public class DragDropListBox : ListBox
{
    public DragDropListBox()
    {
         Style itemContainerStyle        = new Style(typeof(ListBoxItem));
        itemContainerStyle.Setters.Add(new EventSetter(ListBoxItem.DropEvent, new DragEventHandler(ListBoxItemDropHandler)));
        this.ItemContainerStyle         = itemContainerStyle;
    }        
}
```

Right now I have set an event setter for the drop event and works fine. How do I set the style to disable mouse hover and mouse selection effect on items based on a flag? Most of the code I found was in XAML. But I need the code for my custom listbox. Any help would be appreciated.

So far this style is what works for me but its in XAML how do I convert it C# code,specially the visual states and storyboard..

```
<Style x:Key="ListBoxItemStyleTransparentSelect" TargetType="ListBoxItem">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
        <EventSetter Event="Drop" Handler="listbox1_Drop"/>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="ListBoxItem">
                    <Grid Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                        <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                                <VisualState x:Name="Normal"/>
                                <VisualState x:Name="MouseOver">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" To=".35" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Storyboard.TargetName="fillColor"/>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                                <VisualState x:Name="Disabled">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" To=".55" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Storyboard.TargetName="contentPresenter"/>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                            </VisualStateGroup>
                            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="SelectionStates">
                                <VisualState x:Name="Unselected"/>
                                <VisualState x:Name="Selected"/>
                            </VisualStateGroup>
                            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="FocusStates">
                                <VisualState x:Name="Focused"/>
                                <VisualState x:Name="Unfocused"/>
                            </VisualStateGroup>
                        </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                        <Rectangle x:Name="fillColor" IsHitTestVisible="True" Opacity="0" RadiusY="1" RadiusX="1"/>
                        <Rectangle x:Name="fillColor2" IsHitTestVisible="True" Opacity="0" RadiusY="1" RadiusX="1"/>
                        <ContentPresenter x:Name="contentPresenter" ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentTemplate}" Content="{TemplateBinding Content}" HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}"/>
                        <Rectangle x:Name="FocusVisualElement" RadiusY="1" RadiusX="1" StrokeThickness="1" Visibility="Collapsed"/>
                    </Grid>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to modify or replace the `ControlTemplate` for `ListBoxItem` and apply that in your `Style`. For the flag itself you're going to need some bool property to express the value so that it can be used in the template. I would recommend an inherited attached property that you can set on the `DragDropListBox` and then access on the child `ListBoxItems`.

You should absolutely be doing this template work in XAML. Writing a `ControlTemplate` in code is tedious at best and prevents you from using an existing template as a starting point. If you want to keep things like the event hookup in code you can pull in the template XAML from resources and then assign it to a setter in code.

Comment: I know that. Just have a look at the edited question.